# Posts made to Page wall by graph api are not visible to Fan's

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

I have managed to get posts made to a page of which I am admin via the API.

However the problem now is that I can only see the post,  it does not show if another page admin logs in or a guest/fan is viewing the page.

The code below is actually working fine but I have included this for reference anyway.

```
try {
    $page_id = 'crystalwear';
   // $page_info = $facebook->api("/$page_id?fields=access_token");
   // if( $page_info['access_token'] ) {
     // echo "Access Token: " . $page_info['access_token'];
  $args = array(
        'access_token'  =>     '{Page Access Token Here}',
        'message'       => "Today's Deal only $" . number_format($row[2], 2),
        'link'          => "link url",
        'description'   => "Check out our current daily deal. Discounted Costumes/Lingerie Items. You never know what you may find.",
        'picture'       => "https://{website_url/" . zen_image_mod(DIR_WS_IMAGES . $row[4], $row[0], 177, 265),
    );   
$post_id = $facebook->api("/$page_id/feed","post",$args);
//}
} catch(FacebookApiException $e){
    error_log($e);
    }
}
```

Although the post is successful and shows in my admin feed still Fan's and others cannot see the posts.  Anyone have any ideas what would cause this?

Answer (score 8):

same spent hours on net like a nut . remember to check the sandbox option, turn it off it works on me LOL

take a look at [Post to page wall as a page via application not visible to others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997892/post-to-page-wall-as-a-page-via-application-not-visible-to-others)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook gives these kind of post a low priority, posting an image or posting a url generally get a higher priority on news feed.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

use **filter=1** GET parameter:
`http://www.facebook.com/pages/***/[PAGE_ID_HERE]?sk=wall&filter=1`

or change your page settings `https://www.facebook.com/pages/edit/?id=[PAGE_ID_HERE]`
**Wall Tab Shows** parameter to "All posts" to use this filter by default for all users

Comment: Tried both options.  This only ever shows the posts made by the app when I am logged in.  

The page is here.  http://www.facebook.com/crystalwear?sk=wall&filter=1

The last post shown is from November 27th 2011 (Posted Manually on Facebook) Even though the last week I have been posting once daily with the app.

Comment: Snapshot of the page settings on Facebook.  [link](http://www.crystalwear.co.nz/Facebook-Page-Settings.PNG)