# Post to page wall as a page via application not visible to others

Tags: facebook, visibility, facebook-apps, facebook-wall

ONe of my application is posting information on a page (as the page). But it looks like that only me (I am administrator of the page) can see the message. I checked the privacy settings of that message with Graph API explorer and it looks ok:

```
 "privacy": {
    "description": "Public",
    "value": "EVERYONE"
  },
```

One difference I can see is the number of person who has seen the post is written in English (for other posts, it's in french).

What could I have missed?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

LOL after posting this message, I thought "that could be a setting with the application" ... indeed sandbox was still activated .... Problem solved.

Comment: Thank you for posting this! I was having the exact same problem. I checked and rechecked that everything was configured correctly, but completely missed that sandbox mode checkbox. Now it works. I feel so silly...

Answer (score 3):

Lol, the pain that this caused me. Above answer worked for me, the instructions that I found were here:

[How to disable sandbox mode in new facebook app developer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21946125/how-to-disable-sandbox-mode-in-new-facebook-app-developer)