# How to disable sandbox mode in new facebook app developer?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, sandbox

**Question 1:**

Is this the correct way to to disable sandbox mode in the new facebook app developer dashboard?

a) Go to the "Status & Review" section.

b) Select "Yes" after the text "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?"

---

**Question 2:**

I created my fb app so that I can cross-post blog entries from my WordPress blog to my facebook wall.

If I click "Yes" after "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?" will the general public will be able to use my app to post to my facebook account? (Fyi I don't want this to happen.)

---

**Question 3:**

Is it possible to disable Sandbox mode without having to fill out privacy policy info?  I want to be able to use my app - but don't want the app to be searchable in the facebook app center or used by others.

---

Any clarification would be appreciated.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: As for question 1, yes, you will have to select yes for making the app live, and as for question 3, no, you have to fill out the privacy policy info. You can try to add testers if you want specific people to check your application.

Comment: I am in a situation similar like your, but Facebook dosn't allow me to switch from "NO" to "YES" in point 1.b. It says "You must have a valid contact email specified to make this app available to all users"... do you know where must I fill this email that FB requires me?

Comment: There are two places where you can enter your email address: 

1. Click on "Settings" on the left hand side of the screen. Under the "Basic" tab is an input field labeled "Contact Email"

2. Click on "App Details" on the left hand side of the screen.  In the middle of the page is a section labeled "Contact Info".  You can enter a support email address in the "User Support Email" field.

Answer (score 35):

You can see it in the App's Settings then Basic Tab, then fill up the "Contact Email" which is in the right side.

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/xxxxxx/settings/
change xxx to your **app id**

Comment: thats what i was looking for. thanks. My button was disabled and i had no idea why.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the step by step guide:

1. Open https://developers.facebook.com/
2. Select your app from top navigation bar (`Apps`)
3. Click on `Status & Review` (Left Sidebar)
4. You will find a toggle button to do on/off your app from sandbox
   mode. `By default it will on` for sandbox mode if you are creating new app.
   [image]

or you can open url like
[`https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR-APP-ID/review-status/`](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR-APP-ID/review-status/)